# django-tastypie REST update or delete resource with username

Tags: python, django, rest, python-2.7, tastypie

Hi there i am using django tastypie and i can update (PUT) a resource if i provide an id like this :

> http://mysite.com:8000/api/v1/user/1/

But my question is, can i do an update without the id (pk) but with a username instead? And if yes, how can i do that?
It would be something like this :

> http://mysite.com:8000/api/v1/user/username/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is described in [tastypie cookbook](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook.html#using-non-pk-data-for-your-urls)

```
class UserResource(ModelResource):
   class Meta:
      queryset = User.objects.all()

   def prepend_urls(self):
      return [
        url(r"^(?P<resource_name>%s)/(?P<username>[\w\d_.-]+)/$" % self._meta.resource_name, self.wrap_view('dispatch_detail'), name="api_dispatch_detail"),
    ]
```